# How can i verify the proxy used in a GET call using httr?

Tags: r, proxy, httr

I need to validate that the GET request is using the proxy i have set up.

Is there a way to validate the proxy used from the `response`?

```
library(httr)

HTTPUserAgents <- c("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36")
  
link <- paste0("https://www.instagram.com/carlosgcardenasv/")
response <- RETRY(verb = "GET",
                url = link, 
                user_agent(HTTPUserAgents),
                use_proxy(url = "XXXX",
                          port = 8888, 
                          username = "XXXX",
                          password = "XXXX"),
                verbose())
```

Comment: What kind of proxy server as you using? Does it modify your request headers? (This would happen after the request was sent from R so R wouldn't not be able to see these changes - you'd have to know how your proxy is configured.) What does `headers(response)` look like? Do you have a reason to doubt that your request is being proxied here?

Comment: @MrFlick basically i want to use a proxy to avoid getting banned. If i use the command line in the terminal and fetch the same page using the proxy and cookies with `wget` i am able to get a response. Nonetheless when i do it with `httr` it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy can be verified applying a `GET` request to `https://jsonip.com/`. This will return the `IP`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code to follow up on response from @Carlos G. Cardenas V.
Here I am using `rvest::session` but it works the same with `httr::GET`. First you check your IP address and then check if proxy IP is used in next session.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

# get your IP
jsonlite::fromJSON(rvest::html_text(rvest::read_html("http://jsonip.com/")))$ip

# test proxy
session <- rvest::session("http://jsonip.com/",
                          httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"),
                          httr::use_proxy(url = "XXXX", port = 8888, 
                                          username = "XXXX", password = "XXXX"))
page_text <- rvest::html_text(rvest::read_html(session))
proxy_ip <- jsonlite::fromJSON(page_text)$ip
proxy_ip
```